# remove all Decimals and single numbers from array / string

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

so my script generates a big blob of "Piano Notes" which are similar to...

```
 var songNotes  = "...";
```

[the large Piano notes content](http://jsfiddle.net/adhegde001/s9j92vfc/)

and my problem is between the piano notes which i need [also in the fiddle] there are empty ",," and decimal numbers.. so i cant figure out how to remove the empty 
 ,, and decimals as big as 
"1.0416666666642413,0.625,0,g3,1498.9583333333358,,0,c3,1.0416666666642413,0.625,0,c3"
and i want them removed except the the needed words which are

```
var theRightOnes = "s2,as2,cs3,ds3,fs3,gs3,as3,gs3,cs4,ds4,fs4,cs3,as4,gs4,ds5,a2,cs4,b2,c3,a3,ds4,b3,c4,as3,gs2,e3,c3,c4,cs3,ds3,a4,fs3,gs3,as3,g3,f3,b4,c5,a3,d4,as2,e4,g4,d3,b3,b2,f4,a2,d4,e4,cs5,gs1,e2,c2,c3,cs2,ds2,a3,fs2,gs2,as2,g2,f2,b3,c4,a2,d3,as1,e3,g3,d2,b2,b1,f3,a1,d5,e5";
```

so can anyone give me a clue on how this can be accomplished?
if anyone needs more info then i am ready oblige to do so..

Regards - Adarsh Hegde

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/s9j92vfc/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var notesArr = songNotes.split(",");
var len = notesArr.length;
while(len--) {
    if(!notesArr[len] || !isNaN(parseInt(notesArr[len], 10))) {
        notesArr.splice(len, 1);
    } 
}

songNotes = notesArr.join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove all the numbers from notes.

You can say like bellow

```
var notes = songNotes.split(",").filter(function(note){
    return isNaN(note);
});

console.log(notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` (see **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**) to weed out unwanted values:

```
var wantedNotes = songNotes.split(',')
                   .filter(function (v) {
                      return isNaN(+v) && v.trim().length
                   });
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xm2fn6zm/)

Answer (score 0):

just use regular expression,like this:

`var a = "1.0416666666642413,0.625,0,g3,1498.9583333333358,,0,c3,1.0416666666642413,0.625,0,c3";
console.log(a.replace(/\b(\d+(\.\d+)?),+/g,""));`